# KendoDropDownList TabIndex not taking effect

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I'm using the KendoDropDownList widget and in the markup, the select element has `tabindex="600"` set on it.  But it isn't taking effect.  I do see it in the final markup that's rendered to the client.

```
<span style="" title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header form-control"
     unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" 
     aria-expanded="false" tabindex="610" 
     aria-owns="PropertyAddress_State_listbox" 
     aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">

    <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
        <span class="k-input" unselectable="on">CA</span>
        <span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
            <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span
        </span>
    </span>
    <select name="PropertyAddress.State" id="PropertyAddress_State" 
        data-role="dropdownlist" class="form-control" style="display: none;">
      <option value="AK">AK</option>
      <option value="AL">AL</option>
      .
      .
    </select>
</span>
```

But tabbing does not trigger a dropdown as a normal select element would.  any idea how and if it can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Kendo UI DropDownList moves the tabindex from the original element to the visible focusable element ( in this case).
As to the issue, I could not replicate it:

- http://screencast.com/t/I5lKNVbrnjN

Here is the demo:

- http://dojo.telerik.com/uVAvA

Comment: In your demo link on tabbing from drop down the control is going to another drop down control. I think its a problem with Kendo drop down control. Having the same problem in our code as well. Tabbing is not working from DropDownList.